# Source (.) piped curl output

Tags: shell, environment-variables, curl

I have a file, f, on my webserver with the following contents:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

I would like to (from another linux box) do the following, but I can't get the command right:

```
curl http://myserver/f | ?
```

Where the ? will read each line into the current environment.  So, given the above file, this would have the same effect as doing

```
% alias ll='ls -l'
```

in the current shell process.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `eval "$(curl "$URL")"`?

But you better be really sure you get the right URL, and the downloaded code doesn't do anything nasty.

Comment: gets the nod for brevity.  Cautions re: eval duly noted.

Answer (score 5):

In Bash you could try sourcing `/dev/stdin` after redirecting the output of the `curl` command to `/dev/stdin` in a single line like so:

```
source /dev/stdin  <<< "$(curl http://myserver/f)"
```

This should avoid (sourced) variable assignment in a subshell (which would be invisible by the parent shell).

Comment: This works in Bash and zsh.  I like it

Answer (score 0):

Piping always seems to spawn a child shell. Maybe file substitutions are more appropriate here.

```
## this doesn't work
# curl http://myserver/f | . /dev/stdin

## this works
. <(curl http://myserver/f)
```

Comment: Whether the right most part of a pipe line runs in subshell or not depends on the shell. In the bash shell, see also the `lastpipe` option, which once set and for non-interactive shell would make your commented out example work.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, these differences can be very confusing. I've tested it on bash and zsh on a default-ish system, but I didn't know there was a flag for something like this.